# How can I group values from a database using <td> and rowspan?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So, I am reading some values from a database. Such as 'result', 'team', 'league' from a database. I am trying to display, in a `<table>`, results of the specific team grouped by league, something like this:

[image: Picture]

That is assuming my database contains the following data:

```
result1     team1   league1
result2     team1   league1
result100   team1   league2
result101   team1   league2
result88    team1   league2
```

I have tried a lot of stuff and yet I can't get it to work. Also, the league cell must have a `rowspan` equal to the number of results detected in the specific league. This can be done with `mysql_num_rows`, but I don't know exactly where to place it. So how can I get this table to work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have tried "lots of stuff" what have you tried? SO is not a code writing service. We're here to help, but you have to show what you have tried that didn't work. Show what has come closest to working.

Comment: Do you know or understand the HTML you would need to have to generate to get the results you want?

Answer (score 0):

Groupng the output by league is a simple matter of doing a break-sort on the results of your query. Since your question doesn't
include your table schema, or any php code, I've made some assumptions about your table, and will leave opening the connection to
your DB, and executing the sql statement to you.

```
$qstr = "SELECT league, team, event
FROM table
ORDER BY league, team, event";

//  Execute query, get results into  associative array $allrows

$league = "";
$col1 = "";
$col2 = "";
echo "<table>\n";
foreach($allrows as $rowno => $row) {
    if($league != $row['league']) {
        if($league != "") {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<td>".$col1."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$col2."</td>";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        $league = $row['league'];
        $col1 = $league;
        $col2 = "";
    }
    $col2 .= $row['team']." got ".$row['event']."<br />\n";
}
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td>".$col1."</td>";
echo "<td>".$col2."</td>";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try'd some way and it worked for me I hope it works for you...
Look at the code:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=you_dbname', 'user', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'SELECT league, result, team FROM matches_info';
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">'.$row['pcid'].'</td>
    <tr><td>'.$row['pid'].' got '.$row['pc_lect_num'].' </td></tr>
    <tr><td>'.$row['pid'].' got '.$row['pc_lect_num'].'</td></tr></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

It is very basic you can Add more functions to improve the functionality of it.